# How to get usage report of Tabs and Apps for a Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, m365, tabs, msteams-tabs-usage

I have a requirement where I need to get usage of Tabs that have been added to any Microsoft Teams Channel. Example: Wiki, OneNote, Loop, SharePoint Page, Excel Link, Polly , and so on.